# FlashVars and AS2 loading dynamically named text file

Tags: actionscript-2, flashvars

I am attempting to load a dynamically generated textfile into an as2 script.  This file will have a unique name each time.  I have a working as2 script that will load the file just fine when specifically named, but not when I try to load it through a flashvar.

The line from the html that specifies it is here.  When I try to put the full param string here it freaks out, so I truncated the line.

```
FlashVars value="myVariable=mytextfile.txt&mySecondVariable=2"
```

the AS2 load variable here. and I need mydata.txt to be pulled from myVariable

```
my_data.load("mydata.txt");
```

while we are at it, is this the right way to load this flashvar into the scroll_speed? variable.

```
var scroll_speed:Number = mySecondVariable;
```

Comment: I had it working for a minute, then something glitched. doh.  if I figure it out I'll post the answer,